# Assigning NULL value to column name using Case Statement of where is SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table `GrowDaysLocation`. In this table there can be two records with respect to `DistrictId` and `RegionId`

i.e;

- `RegionId=1` and `DistrictId = NULL`
- `RegionId=1` and `DistrictId = 1`

I have a condition that if the row doesn't exist for `RegionId = 1 and DistrictId = 1` then get the row for `RegionId = 1 and DistrictId = NULL`.

How can I accomplish this using a single query?

The below is the query I have tried out.

In this query, I have used CASE in Where clause and Use sub-query to find out the row's existence but the problem is when I return NULL from the case it will not return any rows.

==================================================

```
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF

Select * From GrowDaysLocations 
Where DistrictId = 
( CASE WHEN (Select Count(*) From GrowDaysLocations 
                Where RegionId = '38D95A68-4A92-4D11-9A88-464CF1492880' AND DistrictId = 'F4B67A07-1BF7-42F5-9F19-77329A215D8B' AND 
                GrowDaysProfileId = '79F8BDBF-67D3-44A7-A790-1C10EE8B2AD0') > 0 THEN DistrictId
            ELSE 
                NULL
            END
)   
AND RegionId = '38D95A68-4A92-4D11-9A88-464CF1492880' AND GrowDaysProfileId = '79F8BDBF-67D3-44A7-A790-1C10EE8B2AD0'
```

===========================================

Comment: I don't understand, you say `if the row doesn't exist for RegionId = 1 and DistrictId = 1` but your example implies the row does not exist for a given value of `x` and `y` -- is this true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RANK` function may give you the results you are looking for:

```
SELECT RegionId, DistrictId, GrowDaysProfileId
FROM
    (SELECT RegionId
        ,DistrictId
        ,GrowDaysProfileId
        ,RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY RegionId, GrowDaysProfileId 
                     ORDER BY DistrictId DESC) AS rankVal
    From GrowDaysLocation) sub
WHERE rankVal = 1
```

This query will give you a result set with one row for each distinct `RegionId` and `GrowDaysProfileId`.  If a `RegionId`/`GrowDaysProfileId` combination has more than one row in the table, the query will select a result based on the value of `DistrictId`.  The row with the highest `DistrictId` value will be used first and the row with the lowest `DistrictId` (`NULL` being the lowest) last.

Comment: Nice solution, can't you put the OVER statement in the WHERE and take out the sub-query?

Comment: @Hogan Unfortunately "windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses".

Comment: Thanks,Kevin. Is there any way I can set the column to NULL using CASE statement. –

Answer (score 0):

This is because when evaluating the condition

```
WHERE ColumnName = NULL
```

all rows are filtered out because when checking for equality, if any side is NULL, the row is immediately filtered out regardless of the condition ([see Data Manipulation Language section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28SQL%29#Data_Manipulation_Language)) . You have to use

```
WHERE ColumnName IS NULL
```

In this case you can use

```
WHERE ISNULL(DistrictID, 'Empty') = ...
```

And use the 'Empty' string instead of null in the case statement.

Comment: DistrictID is a UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, so i can't use ISNULL()